# Is ArrayList<String> an extendable class or should it be replaced with ArrayList?

Tags: java, class, arraylist, subclass

Is `ArrayList<String>` a class? If not, why does `public static class StringArrayList extends ArrayList<String>` work?

To compare two strings in `ArrayList<String>` I had to override the ArrayList.contains() method (that is not the question). I did the following:

```
public static class StringArrayList extends ArrayList<String> {

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof String) {
            String element = (String) o;
            for (String str : this) {
                if (str.equals(element)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works. My question is, is ArrayListString a class that can be extended? Is it not an object of type ArrayList? Should the class not be ArrayList instead?

Edit: I am adding the code where contains() didn't work for some reason

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class star
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    //System.out.print("enter test case no");
    int t=sc.nextInt();
    for (int test_case=t;test_case>=1;test_case--)
    {//System.out.print("enter length of string");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        //System.out.print("enter string");
        String str=sc.next();
        ArrayList<String> star = new ArrayList<String>();
      
        for(int seq=0;seq<str.length()-2;seq++)
        {
            //System.out.print("inside for loop");
           if(!star.contains(str.charAt(seq)+str.charAt(seq+1)))
           star.add(""+str.charAt(seq)+str.charAt(seq+1));
        }
    System.out.println(star.size());
}
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you would need to - `ArrayList#contains` will use `Object#equals` to compare the `Object` and elements together

Comment: The issue was without it for some reason it didnt work. So if the ArrayList<String> str contains "ab" and "ba" and i typed str.contains("ab") it gave me false as a return value

Comment: Here are a few resources.  _[Lesson: Introduction to Collections (The Java™ Tutorials > Collections)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html)_, and [Lesson: Custom Collection Implementations (The Java™ Tutorials > Collections)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/custom-implementations/index.html).

Comment: The quick test I did worked just fine - must be something else going on in your code

Comment: I edited and added the code which didnt work without it idk what was the issue though

Comment: If a class is not declared final it can be subclassed. If a method is declared final it cannot be overridden.

Comment: It works, but it's not generally a good idea to subclass it.

Comment: @IvoryAlpaca, when passing the _star.contains_ method a value, you are adding two _char_ values, which will not produce a concatenation, and instead will add the _integer_ values of the _char_ values.

Answer (score 0):

Is ArrayList a class? Well it is a *generic* class. Please read the following to learn more about generic type: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html. You probably want to extend the ArrayList generic class. Please provide more context of what you really want to accomplish. Extending a generic class maybe an overkill solution and not what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the *[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html)* is a class, it extends *[AbstractList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractList.html)*, and implements *[List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)*—among others.

Here is the *[OpenJDK](https://openjdk.org/)* source-code for *[ArrayList](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java)*, *[AbstractList](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java)*, and *[List](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/List.java)*.

The *ArrayList* is not a *final* class, so, yes, it can be sub-classed.
An *ArrayList<String>* is the same class—just, declared with a generic-type parameter.

The *ArrayList* class is what's called a *parameterized class*; it makes use of a *[generic-type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)*, introduced in Java 5.

When you create an instance of *ArrayList*, without specifying a *generic-type*, you're essentially passing in *Object*; as opposed to *String*, in this case.

For example, the following two statements are equivalent.

```java
ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
```

```java
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Generally, you would want to supply the *generic-type*, although it is not required.

There is a subtle error in your code, in the inner for-loop.

```java
if (!star.contains(str.charAt(seq) + str.charAt(seq + 1)))
```

When adding *char* values, they will not be concatenated—like *String* objects.

Instead they will be converted to *int* values.

In this case, if I use *"abc"* as an example, on the first iteration, the value being passed to *star#contains* is *195*, and not *"ab"*.

Here is an evaluation.

```java
str.charAt(seq)     = 'a' /* 0x61, 97 */
str.charAt(seq + 1) = 'b' /* 0x62, 98 */
                          /* 97 + 98 = 195 */
```

Thus, a *false* is being returned.

There are a few ways to correct the error.

The most common approach would be to use a *[String#valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char))* call, which will return a *char* value as a *String*.
As a note, since adding a *String* and a *char* together will result in concatenation, you only have to parse one of the values.

```java
if (!star.contains(String.valueOf(str.charAt(seq)) + str.charAt(seq + 1)))
```

Your *star#add* call is already achieving the same result by using an initial empty-string.

```java
star.add("" + str.charAt(seq) + str.charAt(seq + 1));
```

Is equivalent to

```java
star.add(("" + str.charAt(seq)) + str.charAt(seq + 1));
```

As a recommendation, although it is not required, you can create a local variable to hold the concatenated value, since you're using it more than once.

In this example, I created a new variable, *String string*.

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
//System.out.print("enter test case no");
String string;
int t = sc.nextInt();
for (int test_case = t; test_case >= 1; test_case--) {//System.out.print("enter length of string");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    //System.out.print("enter string");
    String str = sc.next();
    ArrayList<String> star = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int seq = 0; seq < str.length() - 2; seq++) {
        //System.out.print("inside for loop");
        string = String.valueOf(str.charAt(seq)) + str.charAt(seq + 1);
        if (!star.contains(string)) star.add(string);
    }
    System.out.println(star.size());
}
```

Input

```
1
3
abc
```

Output

```
1
```